# Windows 10 - USB to parallel software

Tags: windows-10, usb, parallel-port

I would like to use the outputs from a parallel port for home automation.  To do this I need to be able to switch the pins individually but Win10 no longer supports the parallel port.
Can I use a USB to parallel converter?  What Win10 compatible software would be suitable?

Comment: Typically you would write your own software

Comment: AT Ramhound -  What do you mean "typically".. In the past people used usb-parallel adaptors and that may still be the case in win10, (and as with any hardware, people tend to use the drivers that are written for that hardware), and nowadays almost nobody has or uses parallel ports  so what do you mean "typically".  I really don't think you're trying to say that you know how to write drivers for such hardware - other peoples' hardware too.. so why suggest to him to write his own.

Comment: To the original poster raysputin,  i'm sure usb-parallel adaptors are very cheap, why don't you get one and try it.  Maybe the driver  it comes with will work.

Comment: AT Ramhound, and if you mean writing software for the parallel port directly,  then you haven't addressed that he has said that hte parallel port isn't supported in windows 10, and you should, if you think you can write software for it then it'd be helpful if you linked to a SO post about it, if that's what you meant to say.

Comment: @barlop - I am not going to address your questions, if you continue to talk down to me like that.  When I say software, I mean software to communicate with the USB device, **I am not that much of an idiot** to suggest he write software to communicate over the parallel port on Windows 10.  I know you believe I am that idiot, based on your previous comments towards me, but I actually know stuff.

Comment: "you think you can write software for it then it'd be helpful if you linked to a SO post about it" - I am no longer an active member over at Stackoverflow community.  **I will never ask another answer or answer another question at Stackoverflow**, because of the moderators unwillingness to disassociate questions from my account that were downvoted because of revenge voting.  I tried more than 3 times, every single time I made the request, my request was denied.  So yeah, submitting a solution to communicate with a USB Parallel device, will never happen.

Comment: I aplogize if I sound a little upset, Actually, I am upset.  I have seen every comment @barlop has directed towards me.  I have ignored nearly all of them, but something about these particular comments, got under my skin.  I am human.

Comment: AT Ramhound. I would suggest that in the case of revenge downvotes, you don't take them too seriously.Ur rep there is pretty high / not low, and some revenge downvoters would have a negligible affect on your rep points(percentage-wise).I think in the early days/years of stackoverflow the mods used to reply to that and reverse it but their policy changed and they don't,they leave it to the automated system to reverse revenge downvotes if it detects them.But really I wouldn't take revenge downvotes so personally,or seriously since their effect on overall rep is tiny..I've had it loads of times.